# What is the relationship between these 2 formulas in the context of naive Bayes classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, naive-bayes

In ["Kevin Patrick Murphy. Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective."](http://noiselab.ucsd.edu/ECE228/Murphy_Machine_Learning.pdf) (p. 83 in the book / p. 114 in the pdf) the author gives this formula to train a naive Bayes classifier:

$$p(\mathbf{x}_i,y_i|\theta)=p(y_i|\pi) \prod_j p(x_{ij}|\theta_j) = \prod_c\pi_c^{\mathbb{I}(y_i=c)}\prod_j \prod_c p(x_{ij}|\theta_{jc})^{\mathbb{I}(y_i=c)}$$

while [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) gives the formula

$$ p(C_{k}\mid \mathbf {x} )={\frac {p(C_{k})\ p(\mathbf {x} \mid C_{k})}{p(\mathbf {x} )}}\,$$

which is different to equation 3.55. What is the relationship between these 2 formulas?